# coord_trans and coord_flip in same plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use both coord_trans and coord_flip in the same plot, but that seems to not work. Any suggestion how to use coord_trans for a plot that needs to be flipped?
Using `scale_y_log10` does not work since it messes up the `stat_summary`

```
p <- ggplot(df.2,aes(reorder(x,y),y,colour=z)) +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.2,size=0.1) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 8) +
  stat_summary(
    fun = mean, 
    geom = "errorbar", 
    aes(ymax = ..y.., ymin = ..y..), 
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.1), 
    width = 0.7,
    colour="black") +
  coord_flip() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  labs(x="",y="") +
  scale_color_manual(values = mycolors)
p + coord_trans(y = "log10")
```

Comment: The `coord_flip()` is largely redudant nowadays. You can simply swap `x` and `y` and if that does not work out of the box, you can set `orientation = "y"` to a geom/stat layer. See [blog post](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/ggplot2-3-3-0/#bi-directional-geoms-and-stats).

Comment: This works (swapping x an y and setting orientation ="y" in stat_summary), but still the mean in the stat_summary is not changing when  adding scale_x_log10()

Answer (score 0):

Package `deeptime`'s [coord_trans_flip](https://rdrr.io/github/willgearty/deeptime/man/coord_trans_flip.html) function seems to be the solution, as it flips the axes after transformation.

I couldn't find any native ggplot2 solution either.